# my Realtime Database firebase keep refreshing won't display data in console

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

my Realtime Database firebase keep refreshing won't display data in console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSifl.jpg)

it was working normally

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcp0k.jpg)

Comment: Check the JavaScript console of your browser for relevant error message. If nothing shows, try it in an incognito window, on a different browser, and/or on a different network.

Comment: thank you sir, same problem only when i use different netwwork, but i can't use different in all my project i need to use mine,so is there solution, i added new screenshot